# What's a good Java idiom for concatenating multiple lists with a single command?

Tags: java, list, api, collections, concatenation

I want to concatenate multiple lists with a *single* command, e.g. to do something like:

```
myFirstList.concat(mySecondList).concat(myThirdList);
```

or maybe

```
List.concat(myFirstList, mySecondList,myThirdList);
```

i.e. I'd like something like

```
List<T> concat(List<T> additional);
```

as a member of `List` (can't have that, I guess... :-( ), or

```
static <T> List<T> concat(List<T>... lists);
```

which is more doable. Does any package have this?

**Note:**

Yes, I know I can use `addAll()`, but that returns a boolean, so you can't use it repeatedly in the same command.

Comment: It doesn't chain but List has the method addAll. Is there really a need for this chaining ?

Comment: @dystroy: I didn't say there's a *need*. Obviously Java is Turing-complete without it... I'm looking for a convenience idiom.

Comment: The problem is that in order to have a coherent language/framework, you would have to do this with many many functions. That simply wasn't how the standard lib were designed. I don't say it's good as it is (java verbosity is painful) but having chaining ability just on one method only breaks the coherency and doesn't help.

Comment: @dystroy: But I'm not asking about the standard libraries necessarily. Guava doesn't have something like this, nor does Apache Commons.Collections. I ended up writing a small method myself but that doesn't sound like the Right Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use [addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method:

```
List<String> testList1 = new ArrayList<String>();           
testList1.add("one");
testList1.add("two");

List<String> testList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
testList2.add("three");

testList2.addAll(testList1);
//testList2 now has "three","one","two"
```

Comment: Edited the question to clarify why this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addAll` method and create a small builder for this:

```
class ListBuilder<T> {
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    public ListBuilder<T> concat(List<T> other) {
        this.list.addAll(other);
        return this;
    }

    public List<T> getAll() {
        return this.list;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ListBuilder<String> builder = new ListBuilder<String>();
builder.concat(myFirstList).concat(mySecondList).concat(myThirdList);

System.out.println(builder.getAll());
```

Comment: Adding overhead just to make java look like another language doesn't seem, in my opinion, a good idea. This could be a pattern when building a whole new utility but not just for this. [not a critic of this answer but a general comment]